# ExtJS Infinite Scroll without totalProperty

Tags: extjs, extjs6

In ExtJs, we always need totalProperty in order to get the pagination works.
But this requires the backend to retrieve all data in order to calculate the "total count".

Is there a way that extjs pagination/infinite scrolling work without total count? So that we just keep scrolling until it has no more record and ends there.

Comment: This is not an ExtJS issue, it's a math problem. How would you size the scrollbar without knowing the estimated record count? The backend only needs to return a property with the totalCount, not all records for you to count on the client side.

Comment: I think Neo is looking for something like what facebook does.  They keep growing the scroll bar has the user scrolls down.  As you get to the end of the current dataset more are added.  This makes for a poor user experience.  You could create such a component with extjs using the many scroll methods, onScrollEnd, onScrollMove, onScrollStart etc...   With that said, most modern database allow for a count(*) which will return the total record count for a given query.

Comment: @mcg1103 ya, that's what I'm looking. Seems like there's no way in ExtJS then other than to code it myself. Not too much a BE/database guy. Not sure if cassandra can do that. But anyhow, you still need to read the all the record in order to get the count (logically) , am i right? .

Comment: Then you are not looking for a server side store that returns all records. Basically what you want is a client side grid with a scroll listener that every time you reach the end, you download another 10, 100 records (depending on how big your row is). There other grids that will do what you want out of the box. ExtJS will not.

Answer (score 3):

The totalCount property can be changed during the next AJAX request (it is not constant value). The following sample for classic toolkit v 7.1 works:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',
    launch: function () {


        // Store Model
        Ext.define('ForumThread', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

            fields: [
                'title'
            ]
        });

        // Named Buffered Store
        Ext.create('Ext.data.BufferedStore', {
            storeId: 'threadsStore',

            model: 'ForumThread',

            leadingBufferZone: 2,
            pageSize: 10,

            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'data1.json',
                reader: {
                    rootProperty: 'topics',
                    totalProperty: 'totalCount'
                },
            },
            autoLoad: true,
        });

        // Infinite Grid using the Buffered Store
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            title: "Infinite Grid",

            store: "threadsStore",

            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            width: "100%",
            height: 400,

            features: [{
                ftype: 'grouping',
            }],

            plugins: [{
                ptype: 'bufferedrenderer'
            }],

            columns: [{
                dataIndex: 'title',
                flex: 1
            }]


        });
    }
});
```

and the dynamic data:

```
var totalCount = params.start + 10*params.limit;
var topics = [];
for(i=params.start; i<params.start+params.limit; i++) {
    topics.push({
        title: 'title_' + i
    })
}
return {
    "totalCount": totalCount,
    "topics": topics
};
```

Comment: do you mean add it in the beforeprefetch event?
changing totalCount of the store will not break the grid?

Comment: No, I mean change the totalCount on the server side.

Comment: I see. so every request , the total will increase.. i see. never thought of that .cool. Thanks for suggestion.